# Getting wrong positions in Listview when scrolling

Tags: java, android, listview, position, adapter

i'm using a customadapter for my listview. In my Activity I have some Listeners to mark selcted Items (first time with log tap, then short tap)
It works until the list becomes big enough to become scrollable. In this case if I mark one item and scroll down, there are other items that are marked too, and if i scroll fast, the marked items will change. I heard, that the ListView is recycling somehow the positions oder something like that, but I tink the position should be stay the same.

Here is my CustomAdapter: (if you see some possibilitys for performanceimprovement mention it too)

```
public class CustomAdapterMain extends BaseAdapter {

private ArrayList<Kontakt> listItems;
private LayoutInflater layoutInflater;
private Kontakt kontakt;
private int position;
private ViewHolder viewHolder;
private Integer Kalenderjahr=Calendar.getInstance().get(Calendar.YEAR);
private Integer Kalendermonat=Calendar.getInstance().get(Calendar.MONTH);
private Integer Kalendertag=Calendar.getInstance().get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
TinyDB tinyDB;

public CustomAdapterMain(Context context, ArrayList<Kontakt> arrayList){
    listItems=arrayList;
    //layoutInflater=(LayoutInflater)context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    layoutInflater=LayoutInflater.from(context);
    tinyDB= new TinyDB(context);
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return listItems.size();
}

@Override
public Kontakt getItem(int position) {
    return listItems.get(position);
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return position;
}
@Override
public View getView(int position, View view, ViewGroup parent){
    if(view==null){
        viewHolder=new ViewHolder();
        view=layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.chat_list_view_item, parent, false);
        viewHolder.listView=view.findViewById(R.id.Chats);
        viewHolder.Kontaktname=view.findViewById(R.id.kontakt_item_name_chat);
        viewHolder.Chatsnippet=view.findViewById(R.id.kontakt_item_chatsnippet);
        viewHolder.Uhrzeit=view.findViewById(R.id.kontakt_item_uhrzeit);
        view.setTag(viewHolder);
    }
    else{
        viewHolder=(ViewHolder)view.getTag();
    }
    Kontakt kontaktItem=listItems.get(position);
    if(kontakt!=null){
        viewHolder.kontakt.setKontakt(kontaktItem);
    }
    else{
        //viewHolder.kontakt=kontaktItem.getKontakt();

    }

    String last_massage=tinyDB.getString(kontaktItem.getNummer()+"text");
    String last_massage_time=tinyDB.getString(kontaktItem.getNummer()+"time");
    String[] Uhrzeit=last_massage_time.split(" ");
    String[] Datum=Uhrzeit[0].split("-");
    String[] Stunden=Uhrzeit[1].split(":");

    Integer Jahr=Integer.parseInt(Datum[0]);
    Integer Monat=Integer.parseInt(Datum[1]);
    Integer Tag=Integer.parseInt(Datum[2]);

    if(Jahr<Kalenderjahr||Monat<Kalendermonat||Tag+1<Kalendertag){
        viewHolder.Uhrzeit.setText(Tag+"."+Monat+"."+Jahr%1000);
    }
    else if(Tag<Kalendertag){
        viewHolder.Uhrzeit.setText(R.string.gestern);
    }
    else{
        viewHolder.Uhrzeit.setText(Stunden[0]+":"+Stunden[1]);
    }

    viewHolder.Kontaktname.setText(kontaktItem.getName());
    viewHolder.Chatsnippet.setText(last_massage);
    //set Image from server

    return view;
}
}
```

My onClickListeners: (also tried   parent.getChildAt(position).setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.orange)); )

```
 Chats=findViewById(R.id.Chats);
    final CustomAdapterMain customadapter=new                                           CustomAdapterMain(YouniChat_MainActivity.this,ArrayListChats);
    Chats.setAdapter(customadapter);
 Chats.setOnItemLongClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemLongClickListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            hasClicked.put(position,false);
            view.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.orange));
            marked++;
            Chats.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onItemClick(AdapterView parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                    if(hasClicked.get(position,true)) {
                        view.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.orange));
                        marked++;
                        hasClicked.put(position, false);
                    }
                    else{
                        view.setBackgroundColor(0);
                        marked--;
                        hasClicked.put(position, true);
                    }
                    if(marked>0){
                        findViewById(R.id.delete).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    }
                    else{
                        findViewById(R.id.delete).setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                        onClickListener();
                    }
                }
            });
            if(marked>0) {
                findViewById(R.id.delete).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            }
            else{
                findViewById(R.id.delete).setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                onClickListener();
            }
            return true; //damit nicht der OnItemClickListener reagiert
        }
    });
```

Comment: I can infer from the code that you are trying to achieve sort of multi select mode only on long click and then add items to selection on single click as well. Is this what you are trying to achieve?

Comment: Yes, like its normal in chatapps

Comment: Die failure exists too when I'll select only one item (only long tap)

Comment: This is called contextual action mode. Read here. https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/menus#CAB. Other than this you should use `RecyclerView` and pass POJO list to `RecyclerView Adapter`. Set listeners on list item view and change a property in POJO to highlight if its selected.